# Linux command to create the empty file called 'test1'

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, command, computer-science

Enter a Linux command to create the empty file called 'test1' in the directory 'systems' (you are still in your home directory).

Comment: How about `touch filename`?

Comment: I've tried that already

Comment: So? Any error messages? Or unexpected results?

Comment: i apologize that is the right answer :) thanks for your help there was a spelling error I had

Comment: You have not stated where the directory "systems" is located with respect to your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'systems' is a subdirectory of the current directory:
`touch systems/test1`

Assuming that you only know that the directory 'systems' is some subdirectory in the directory tree of the current directory then: `find . -name systems -type d -exec touch "{}/test1" \;` Will create such a file.  Alternately, so will `find . -name systems -type d -execdir touch systems/test1 \;` However, both will do so in every subdirectory named 'systems' in the current directory tree. We could limit that action to only the first, the last, or some other criteria, but the list of possible permutations is just too long.

You really have not provided enough information for us to provide a complete answer.